# Why does using Nsurl request keeps telling me to rename to "init(url)"

Tags: ios, swift, nsurl

Also trying to add the ability to detect a video and download it to the application in short a web-based app used for download any kind of video and has the ability to store it within the app

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var Webview: UIWebView!
    @IBOutlet var SearchBar: UISearchBar!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.google.com")
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url! as URL) Webview.loadRequest(request)
        SearchBar.text = "http://"
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchbar: UISearchBar) {
        searchbar.resignFirstResponder()
        let text = SearchBar.text
        let url = NSURL(string: text!)
        let urlRequest:URLRequest = URLRequest(url: url! as URL)

        //  let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url! as URL)

        Webview.loadRequest(urlRequest)
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't use `NSURL` or `NSURLRequest` in Swift. Use `URL` and `URLRequest`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You need to use like this in swift**

```
if let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com"){
    let requestObj = URLRequest(url: url)
    Webview.loadRequest(requestObj)
}
```

Comment: i came across a problem i cant seem to get my search bar working if i put an address nothing happens

Comment: @manuel your delegate method not called with your this code please check your question for an answer I update it.

Answer (score 1):

**[URL :](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url)**

URL is a swift struct, so is passed by value.

**[NSURL :](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl)**

NSURL is an Objective-C class. Is inherits from `NSObject`

- In general, prefer the new struct versions of things unless you need to subclass for some reason.
- An object representing the location of a resource that bridges to `URL`; use `NSURL` when you need reference semantics or other Foundation-specific behavior.

Both `URL` and `NSURL` is accepted in swift. but you have used swift then most refer `URL` [MORE](https://nshipster.com/nsurl/).

Answer (score 0):

Use `URL` and `URLRequest` instead `NSURL` and `NSURLRequest` in Swift.

```
let url = URL.init(string: "https://www.google.com")
let request = URLRequest.init(url: url!)
Webview.loadRequest(request)
```

**For Reference you can refer :** [**Reference**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl)