# WKWebView Unsupported Url Error On Https URL

Tags: swift, wkwebview

In my `WKWebView`, I get an error code 6 (unsupported URL) error when I load this URL: https://www.cnet.com/reviews/microsoft-surface-headphones-preview/

Every other URL I've tested works fine, and the above link works in Safari...

I defined the following delegate function:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,
             didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!,
             withError error: Error) {
     presentErrorAlert()
}
```

If I don't define this function, then the page looks fine. So right now, my hacky solution is as follows:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,
            didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!,
             withError error: Error) {
    if error.localizedDescription != "unsupported URL" {
         presentErrorAlert()
    }
}
```

However, I've been scratching my head all day as to why this page in particular causes an error, and I'm concerned that my solution will cause actual errors to be ignored, not to mention that it will still fail on this page in non-English localizations. Any advice?

Comment: Try this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/52252357/10150796

Comment: That URL looks fine, maybe there's another URL that triggers this.

Comment: Try to see what print(webView.url?.absoluteString) shows when that error comes. This will show the url for which the error is coming.