# WK WebView calling completion handler but now showing anything

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I want to load privacy policy (simple string) from server say, **https://*****.com/privacy-policy.html** to my app.

What I have tried till now is given below:

```
class TermsAndConditionsDetailViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var contentView: UIView!
    var webView: WKWebView!

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,
                 didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("loaded")
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        webView = WKWebView()
        contentView.addSubview(webView)
        let myURL = URL(string: "https://***.com/privacy-policy.html")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.navigationDelegate = self

        //I have tried these both one by one
        webView.loadHTMLString("", baseURL: myURL)
        webView.load(myRequest)
     } 
}
```

When i run this code "loaded" gets printed after 2 - 3 seconds but it doesn't show anything on the screen. I have been searching this issue for some time now and have tried to play around with the code. I have cross checked the constraints of all view specially contentView, but no luck.

Comment: your `URL` is working in browser?

Comment: Yes, its working

Comment: @kinza Can you please tell me why you add contentView and add webView as a subview inside that instant of you direct from the storyboard.

Comment: Try this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/52252357/10150796 it's working fine

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani
I have tried the above link but no effect.

Comment: And, I have added webview programatically, because adding it through storyboard gives build error. For more info, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46221577/xcode-9-gm-wkwebview-nscoding-support-was-broken-in-previous-versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to add `frame` for your `WKWebView`

just add

```
webView = WKWebView(frame: self.contentView.frame)
```

after

```
webView = WKWebView()
```

and it will work fine.

Comment: Oh thank you so much. 
This is the reason why I like adding views from storyboard :D